# how to put excutable into war file using maven

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, executable, war

Our web service depends on a third-party executable so we have to deploy the war with it.
Since war file will be unzipped and placed into tomcat webapps folder, I am wondering if there is any way I can place the executable in the war so it can be unzipped by tomcat when it deploys and then I can call it from my java code.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say, that the executable (by the way: native or something else?) is in a separate zip within the war?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing recently, whereby I needed to ship a .dll with my java executable. Not sure if this is the best style, but it worked: I packed the .dll into my jar, extracted (copied) it to system 'temp' folder, and called System.load().

But in your case, I think such an approach might get tangled up with tomcat security rules. Can anyone offer some insight into if those rules can be modified to allow the webapp to run another executable?

Else, is there some sort of tomcat "endorsed" folder in which an executable can be placed. If it's a somewhat static executable (wont change so often) then you might be able to deploy it to tomcat just once (separately to your war).

Good luck.